# preliquibase-spring-boot-starter throwing error when application starting up

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to utilise the pre script (create schema) before starting my application. However im getting the following error:

```
spring boot version 2.7.15
liquibase 4.9.0
pre-liquibase 1.4.0


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [net.lbruun.springboot.preliquibase.PreLiquibaseAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2aae9190]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseConnectionDetails
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseConnectionDetails
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 97 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Your versions of Pre-Liquibase and Spring Boot are not compatible. As [documented in the README](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase?tab=readme-ov-file#spring-boot-compatibility), Pre-Liquibase 1.4.0 requires Spring Boot 3.1. Alternatively, if you want to use Spring Boot 2.7.x, you should use Pre-Liquibase 1.2.x.

Comment: btw, pre-liquibase 1.3.x works fine with Spring Boot 2.7.x also